# Create an object constructor in JS that consists of native properties (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I am wondering how I can automate the setting a group of properties in an DOM element. I know it doesn't work like this, but see the code to understand what I mean:

```
function interface(bg, color, size, margin, content) {
    this.style.backgroundColor=bg; //native html properties
    this.style.color= last;
    this.style.fontSize = size;
    this.style.marginLeft = margin;
    this.innerHTML=content;
}

var Green = new interface("green", "white", "20px", "20", "the green one");
var Blu = new interface("blue", "white", "48px", "0", "the blue one");

document.getElementById("demo").interface = Green;
```

So that the group of properties applies without having to point to them one by one again. Am I completely off?

Comment: Just iterate over the properties and copy them? Various libraries implement such a function, it's easy to write your own, or use the standard [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). You might needs some "deep extension" functionality to handle `style` properly.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not sure it's accurate to call `Object.assign` "standard" at this point.

Comment: @JLRishe: It's part of ECMAScript 6. How much more standard can it become?

Comment: @FelixKling Well, I'm looking at the big green box at the top of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Or is that notice out of date? It's also only supported on one major browser right now, so even if it is "standard", it doesn't have much browser support.

Comment: @FelixKling, it's part of the ES6 *proposal*. It is still a draft and the spec can still change.

Comment: @anstosa: Fair enough, though I doubt `Object.assign` will go away :)

Comment: @JLRishe: That's why we have polyfills.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not a big fan of polyfills, especially since there's always the small possibility that the defined behavior for `Object.assign` can change before the spec is finalized and break code that was relying on the polyfill. Unlikely to happen, sure, but still a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you want to do it this way, but a possibility.

```js
function Interface(bg, color, size, margin, content) {
    this.bg = bg;
    this.color = color;
    this.size = size;
    this.margin = margin;
    this.content = content;
}

Interface.prototype.implement = function (element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = this.bg;
    element.style.color = this.color;
    element.style.fontSize = this.size;
    element.style.marginLeft = this.margin;
    element.innerHTML = this.content;
};

var green = new Interface("green", "white", "20px", "20px", "the green one"),
    blu = new Interface("blue", "white", "48px", "0", "the blue one");

green.implement(document.getElementById("demo"));
```

```html
<div id="demo">Demo</div>
```

**Addition**

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (ECMA6) was mentioned by @FelixKling as a possible solution, but it would need to be a deep extend and it only provides a shallow extend. Here is an example of a basic deep extend (ECMA5).

```js
/*global document */
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var assigner = function (target) {
            if (target && typeof target === 'object') {
                Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function (source) {
                    if (source && typeof source === 'object') {
                        Object.keys(source).forEach(function (key) {
                            var copy = source[key],
                                src,
                                clone,
                                type;

                            if (target !== copy) {
                                type = typeof copy;
                                if (type === 'object') {
                                    src = target[key];
                                    if (src && typeof src === 'object') {
                                        clone = src;
                                    } else {
                                        clone = {};
                                    }

                                    target[key] = assigner(clone, copy);
                                } else if (type !== 'undefined') {
                                    target[key] = copy;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            return target;
        },

        green = {
            style: {
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: '20px',
                marginLeft: '20'
            },
            innerHTML: 'the green one'
        };

    assigner(document.getElementById("demo"), green);
}());
```

```html
<div id="demo">Demo</div>
```

Maybe someone has a way to use `Object.assign` in a generic deep manner?

Comment: You've misspelled "implement". :) But perhaps "apply" would be a better name for it.

Comment: Yes. :) I was trying to avoid the use of `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Xotic has provided a fine answer, but another interesting way you could do this is to have your function generate other functions that carry out the work:

```js
function makeDomUpdater(bg, color, size, margin, content) {
  return function(element){
    element.style.backgroundColor = bg;
    element.style.color = color;
    element.style.fontSize = size;
    element.style.marginLeft = margin;
    element.innerHTML = content;
  };
}

var green = makeDomUpdater("green", "white", "20px", "20", "the green one"),
    blu = makeDomUpdater("blue", "white", "48px", "0", "the blue one");

green(document.getElementById("demo"));
```

```html
<div id="demo">Demo</div>
```

This doesn't make use of object constructors, but then again, not everything has to. :)

Comment: Something to be aware of, `interface` is a [(future) reserved word.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords)

Answer (score 0):

First off, to understand classes, prototype, constructors etc. in JavaScript (this seems to be what you are heading for), I can recommend the free book (which you can also buy as paperback): http://eloquentjavascript.net/. You should take the time to dig into this, the concepts are somewhat different than what you might be coming from (language-wise).

I know you just used this as an example, but for all those styling properties you should use an HTML class and respective CSS definitions. To apply them to an element, you would just have to assign the class. That way, the DOM element would „implement the CSS interface `green`“, so to speak. I would handle the content separately.

```
.green {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px; // margin-left needs a unit
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-left: 0; // at least if it isn't zero
}
```

For working JavaScript code similar to your's, see [JLRishe's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115180/95033) and [Xotic750's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115002/95033) answers.